# Binding in RecyclerView binds data to multiple rows

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

I become crazy with databinding in RecyclerView. The problem is that it binds data to multiple rows and I can't figure out why.

I simplified my code as much as possible. When we start the application there is a 200 rows with a label (empty value by default) and a button. When I click a button my label changes it's value.

So here is a opened activity. As you can see no label is displayed.

[image]

Let's click a button at the first row

[image]

As expected label appearned at correct position. Let's scroll now.

[image]

We can see that label appeared also at 11th position, 21st, etc. Any ideas why?

My Adapter:

```
 @NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    ListLearnItemBinding itemBinding = ListLearnItemBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false);
    return new LearnItemViewHolder(itemBinding);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final LearnItemViewHolder viewHolder = (LearnItemViewHolder) holder;
    // init binding
    if(viewHolder.getBinding().getItem2() == null){
        TestBinding t = new TestBinding();
        t.setRating("");
        viewHolder.getBinding().setItem2(t);
    }

    viewHolder.getBinding().test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            TestBinding item2 = new TestBinding();
            item2.setRating("Label");
            viewHolder.bind(item2);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 200;
}
```

ViewHolder:

```
public class LearnItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ListLearnItemBinding getBinding() {
        return binding;
    }

    private final ListLearnItemBinding binding;

    public LearnItemViewHolder(ListLearnItemBinding binding) {
        super(binding.getRoot());
        this.binding = binding;
    }

    public void bind(TestBinding testItem) {
        binding.setItem2(testItem);
        binding.executePendingBindings();
    }
}
```

Binding model

```
public class TestBinding {
    public String getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(String rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    private String rating;
}
```

OnCreate of my view

```
    binding.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
    binding.recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    LearnAdapter mAdapter = new LearnAdapter(this, data);     
    binding.recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Layout

```
  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@{String.valueOf(item2.rating)}" />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/test"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
      />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because when you're scrolling old views are being resused for optimization.
You need something like this :

```
private List<String> mList;

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final LearnItemViewHolder viewHolder = (LearnItemViewHolder) holder;

    TestBinding t = new TestBinding();
    t.setRating(mList.get( position);
    viewHolder.bind(t);

    viewHolder.getBinding().test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            TestBinding item2 = new TestBinding();
            String label ="Label";
            item2.setRating(label);
            mList.set(position, label);
            viewHolder.bind(item2);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mList.size();
}
```